# How to define a variable domain to be non-continuous range

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd, sicstus-prolog

I'm starting with SICStus Prolog and I would like to define a variable, say `StartingTimes`, to have a domain defined by list `[1, 5, 10]`

How can I do it in SICStus Prolog?

I would do something like:

```
 domain(StartingTimes, 1, 10)
 StartingTimes #= 1 #\/ StartingTimes #= 5 #\/ StartingTimes #= 10
```

But that is horrible. There must be a simple way how to do that. Maybe `fd_sets`?

Note: I tried to find out how it is done in manual but the prolog uses common words and it's really hard to use google for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)). 
?- StartingTimes in {1,5,10}.
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've been looking for.